# Fixing my refresh rate

Tags: display, mojave, resolution

I hope this is the right place to post this question.
I'm getting crazy since 2 days trying to enable 60hz on my external display.

I bought a new LG Ultrafine 4k display as suggested by apple to have a kind of retina resolution on my external monitor and yes, it is awesome, it looks like my MacBook Pro.

I have a new MacBook Pro 2018 with retina display and it is running on macOS Mojave 10.14.3 (I did not updated it, I received it with this OS).

The BIG issue is that my display is capped at 30hz and I don't know how to unlock it back to 60hz.

Reading on Google so far I tried:

- To install a [patch](https://github.com/Floris497/mac-pixel-clock-patch-V2/blob/master/IOKit-patcher.command): no success;
- To install SwitchResX: it doesn't have a 4k version at 60hz, all custom resolution I created are invalid, so, no success;
- Tried to follow a guide to install Lilu + WhateverGreen kexts but it doesn't exist a guide that realy explain how to install it, and how to let it work. People assume everyone speak their language. Running an App called Clover Configurator but I don't know what should I do with it.

Please, can you help me to let it work? What should I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that Apple has the refresh rate locked at 30Hz for that type of resolution:
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206587

> The following Mac models support resolutions and refresh rates of up to 1080p at 60Hz, and 3840 x 2160 at 30Hz, over HDMI 1.4b when using the Apple USB-C Digital AV Multiport Adapter with macOS Sierra 10.12 or later:

- iMac (2017 and later)
- iMac Pro (2017)
- MacBook (2015 and later)
- MacBook Air (Retina, 13-inch, 2018)
- MacBook Pro (2016 and later)

Looking a bit further down on that link, it seems you can try to get it to 60hz by using the right cable and adapter:

> The computers listed above also support 60Hz refresh rate over HDMI when used with a supported HDMI 2.0 display, HDMI Premium Certified cable, and a compatible third-party USB-C to HDMI 2.0 adapter.